# Building app, node modules together in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, development-environment, node-modules

I'll have 4-5 node modules and application developing together. But WebStorm always opening one project in a WebStorm window. In Visual Studio there is a solution which may have multiple projects but I don't know there is a way to do same in WebStorm.

Is there any way to build them together and making release and updates in one IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

**No** -- WebStorm can open only one project per window/frame.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7968 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**Yes** -- you can add content from another project into current one by using **Content Root** functionality. For that: `Settings/Preferences | Project | Directories` -- use `Add Content Root` button to add such additional folder. Once added it will be shown in Project View as separate node.

NOTE: it still counts as one project (which means: the same project settings applied to all content roots).